# Keeping the `names` attribute in `format()`

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a complicated object print nicely in a tibble. Each object has an id number stored in the `names` attribute for easy access that I'd like to display in the tibble. For some reasons, the `names` attribute is lost in `format()` (see the example below).

```r
format.foo <- function(x, ...) {
  print(attributes(x))
  sprintf("<%s>", names(x))
}

df <- tibble::tibble(x = {
  out <- structure(letters[1:5], bar = "zig", class = "foo")
  stats::setNames(out, 1:5)
})

df
#> $bar
#> [1] "zig"
#> 
#> $class
#> [1] "foo"
#> 
#> # A tibble: 5 × 1
#>   x    
#>   <foo>
#> 1 x    
#> 2 <foo>
#> 3 x    
#> 4 <foo>
#> 5 x
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Is there a way to retrieve `names` in `format()`? Using a custom attribute isn't ideal because it forces me to bind the attribute back every time I modify or subset the object.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

- define class-specific formatting which returns a *multi-column* item:

```
format.foo <- function(x, ...) cbind(name = names(x),
                                     bar = attr(x, 'bar') ,
                                     value = x
                                     )
```

- generate some named structure:

```
df <- tibble::tibble(x = {
  out <- structure(letters[1:5], bar = "zig", class = "foo") |>
  stats::setNames(nm = 1:5)
})
```

- format using `format.data.frame` explicitly (which applies a class-specific format column by column):

```
format.data.frame(df)
```

```
  x.name x.bar x.value
1      1   zig       a
2      2   zig       b
3      3   zig       c
4      4   zig       d
5      5   zig       e
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. The original function is returning the output of `setNames` on the `out` object. Your version returns it as a side effect of the assignment operator. They both give the same results. (The OPs `attributes(df$x)` and yours are the same).

Comment: Thanks for your input but that doesn't answer the question. Your syntax using the pipe is equivalent to mine. My issue is related to the `format` function, which drops the `names` attribute.

Comment: oops, thx, forgot the assignment myself ... see update plz

Comment: I'm afraid there's a misunderstanding. `attributes(df$x)` was there for comparison with the `print(attributes(x))` in `format()`. `df$x` behaves as expected and isn't the issue. I removed it from the example to avoid further confusion. The problem has to do with the printing of the `x` vector inside the tibble. `tibble()` relies on `format()` to print values. Though, because the `names` attribute is lost, the values don't show up properly.

Comment: see edit please [unless I got you wrong again ;-)  ]

Comment: I need t keep `format.foo` as is because it defines how to display values of a certain class. Interestingly, calling `format.data.frame(df)` prints the right output. That doesn't really fix the issue though because I need the right output when printing the `df` object, not when calling another function on it.